# is there a way to only have a value in a list if the key appears multiple times in a file?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a dictionary from items in a file. What I have now works but I was wondering if there is a way to only have a list if the key is a duplicate that has different value.so, if I have this

```
micheal math 2
jim chem 3 
jim math 3
pam cs 4
```

expected output:
{micheal:[math,2],jim: [[chem,3], [math,3]], pam: [cs,4]}

actual output:
{micheal:[[math,2]],jim: [[chem,3], [math,3]], pam: [[cs,4]]}

current code:

```
example_dict = {}
for line in dictionary:
     line = (line.strip()).split(' ')
     key = line[0]
     if key not in example_dict
         example_dict[key] = []
     example_dict[key].append(line[1:])
return example_dict
```

Comment: You can use an `str`method and `split`

Comment: I recommend rewriting your question to be clearer, and your output examples too. Your output examples look almost identical and their difference doesn't seem significant relative to what you've asked.

Comment: The actual output is better. The data structure should not change depending on the number of values in the sequence, that only causes trouble down the road (e.g., when iterating over individual values you'd have to check what you're iterating over). That being said, it's probably better to use dictionaries instead of tuple lists as in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

With your current solution, go over your `example_dict` afterward and flatten values that only have one element, e.x.:

```
...

example_dict = {k: (v if len(v) > 1 else v[0]) for k, v in example_dict.items()}
return example_dict
```

Comment: is Always good to learn.  In your aproach, you are iterating line by line or spliting words?

Comment: @AndreNevares this part only flattens the lists after the dictionary is already generated the way OP did it.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like it would make a lot of sense to use dictionaries instead of tuple lists as values.

```py
example_dict = {}
for line in dictionary:
    name, subject, grade = line.strip().split() # optional, but cleaner
    if name not in example_dict:
        example_dict[name] = {}
    example_dict[name][subject] = grade
```

Result:

```py
{'micheal': {'math': '2'},
 'jim': {'chem': '3', 'math': '3'},
 'pam': {'cs': '4'}}
```

Comment: could use `collections.defaultdict` to avoid having an if statement (probably makes it slightly slower, but IMO that's a neater solution)

Comment: @Matiiss I didn't include it as it wasn't part of the question, but good point!